# Compute the density of $Y=|X|$ when $X$ is normally distributed

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> When $X$ has the normal distribution $\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$
>   , compute the density of $Y=|X|$

I know $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\Big(-\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\Big)dx=1$

but the choice of $\mu$ doesn't change the result (integral is always 1), So if we take $\mu=0$ then the function gets even and since $Y$ supports only the positive part we have to multiply the distribution by 2, but can we then translate it back and this is our function ?

$2^{nd}$ Question: what is the difference between distribution and density, in this case they seem to be the same or not ?

Comment: The distribution of $|X|$ is called the [folded normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $P(X \leq u) = P(X \in (-\infty,u]) = P(X \in (-\infty,u)) = \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(u)$, where $$
  \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(u) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^u e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \,dx
$$
is the *cumulative distribution function* (CDF) of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Note that the *density* of $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $$
  \phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$

Now let $Y = |X|$ and $u \geq 0$. The CDF of $|Y|$ is $$\begin{eqnarray}
  P(Y \leq u) &=& P(|X| \leq u) = P(X \in [-u,u])
  = P(X \in (-\infty,u]\setminus (-\infty,-u)) \\
  &=& P(X \in (-\infty,u]) - P(X \in (-\infty,-u))
   =  \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(u) - \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(-u) \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$

To find the *density* of $|Y|$, we differentiate again $$
  \frac{d}{du} P(Y \leq x) = \frac{d}{dx} \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) - \frac{d}{du} \Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(-x) = \phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(x) + \phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}(-x) \text{.}
$$
Thus, the density of $|Y|$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is $$
  f_Y(x) = \begin{cases}
    \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} + e^{-\frac{(x+\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right) &\text{if $u \geq 0$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$

---

Note that this works *regardless* of the specific distribution of $X$ - except in the last line where we defined the resulting density $f_Y$, we never used any specific properties of $\Phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}$ or $\phi_{\mu,\sigma^2}$, except that they are a CDF respectively its density. Thus, it holds for *any* random variable with CDF $F_X$ and density $f_X$ that $|X|$ has the density $$
  f_{|X|}(x) = \begin{cases}
    f_X(x) + f_X(-x) &\text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
    0 &\text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$
and the cumulative distribution function $$
  F_{|X|}(u) = F_{X}(u) - F_{X}(-u) \text{.}
$$
Beware though that the formula for the CDF is *wrong* if $X$ doesn't *have* a density (for example for a discrete distribution), even though the density is never mentioned directly. This is because in the derivation of $F_{|X|}$ we assumed at one point that $P(X \leq u) = P(X < u)$.

Comment: As often the détour PDF$\to$CDF$\to$CDF$\to$PDF is not necessary.

Comment: @Did No, but it's more obvious *why* this works if done that way I think.

Comment: I happen to disagree--but this is no big deal.

Comment: @fgp This answer is more detailed, has just everything that i need, but i've already accepted Did's answer, sorry and thank you very much.

Comment: @derivative If this answer fits your needs more closely, the thing to do is to unaccept the other one and to accept this one.

Comment: @Did OK, but normally i adore your answers :)

Comment: @derivative That's cute to say so... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ has density $f$ then $Y=|X|$ has density $g$ where
$$
g(y)=(f(y)+f(-y))\,\mathbf 1_{y\gt0}.
$$
In the present case,
$$
g(y)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-(y^2+\mu^2)/\sigma^2}\,(\mathrm e^{y\mu/\sigma^2}+\mathrm e^{-y\mu/\sigma^2})}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\,\mathbf 1_{y\gt0}.
$$

Comment: Ok, you've already expanded.

Comment: $P(|X| \leq x)=P(-x \leq X \leq  x)=F_X(x)-F_X(-x)$, then the density of $Y$ is the derivative in  $y$ which is $g_Y(y)=f(y)+f(-y)$.

Comment: @Zbigniew Sorry but the détour PDF→CDF→CDF→PDF is not necessary here.

Comment: @Zbigniew So derivative of the distribution funcion is density, i didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: @Did It is an awkwardness from me. I apologize.

Comment: @Zbigniew No need to apologize... :-)

Comment: My problem with this answer (and the reason I continued typing up my own after you posted yours), is that it doesn't provide any *reasoning* as to why the density is transformed as it is. Now, I trust that for *you* its intuitively clear that we may treat the densitity like a probability here, and just add them up. But if these things were intuitively clear to the OP, we probably wouldn't have asked this question in the first place... Having said that, the answer is of course perfectly *correct*!

Comment: @derivative At my opinion, derivative of cumulative function is the density function.

Comment: @fgp Maybe, maybe not. In any case, it does not seem reasonable to continue forever to go back to CDFs when solving problems involving PDFs, does it? Similarly, one does not continue forever to multiply integers by coming back to successive additions, even if this is the way one did it during a brief period of time...

Comment: $ F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(u) \, du , $
$ f_X(x) = \frac{d}{dx} F_X(x)  $ when  $f_X$ is continuous at $x$

Comment: @Did No, not forever - just until one is firm enough to be able to compute the density of $|X|$ without help ;-) Or, if you're me, whenver you intuition fails you on whether a particular density transformation is correct or not (which I must admit happens way to often... )

Comment: @fgp Now that the dust has settled, let me come back to your last comment. Frankly, I find it illogical... When faced with somebody who asks for help to compute the density of |X|, if one thinks the best method is PDF$\to$PDF instead of PDF$\to$CDF$\to$CDF$\to$PDF, one **must** show the method PDF$\to$PDF, no? Then the asker can learn the latter instead of staying stuck "forever" with the former. Learning to multiply integers instead of staying with the method of repeated additions...

Comment: @Zbigniew A derivative can be discontinuous hence the restriction about $f_X$ in your last comment seems misleading.

Comment: @Did My problem, I guess, is that your answer feels a bit like being conjured out of thin air, and leaves one with the impression that densities can be handled just like probabilities - after all, you just add up the two densities at $x$ and $-x$. Now, I don't doubt for a second that you know *exactly* when and why this works and when and why it doesn't - but the OP probably doesn't. With CDFs, you're on firmer ground - it's not so easy to do invalid operations with events as it is to do them with densities. You'll at least need choice to shoot yourself into your foot ;-)

Comment: @Did You don't *have* to go back to CDFs to avoid this, though. You could just as well state some general-purpose density transformation theorem and derive the result from that. The only reason I usually don't do that, is because I tend to forget the precise statement of these transformation theorems. So I have the choice between looking it up, or going back to CDFs - and then CDFs are usually faster...

Comment: @fgp I see your point. To sum up what I keep from the discussion, I maintain that PDF$\to$PDF should be preferred, on general grounds, to the détour PDF$\to$CDF$\to$CDF$\to$PDF (which is *not* faster, sorry), *and* it was a mistake from my part to omit the Jacobian justification of my answer. Thanks.